# Enzyme - Test if a nested component is correctly rendered

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, meteor, enzyme

I'm trying to test if within my parent component its child component is correctly rendered when the state is updated through a simple boolean value. Below the parent component :

```
class Parent extends Component {
  ...
  render() {
    const { ..., isReady } = this.state;
    const props = { ... };

    return(
      <div className="container page-content">

        { isReady ?
          <Child {...props} />
          :
          <div id="loader-wrapper">
            <div id="loader"></div>
          </div>
        }

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My test is :

```
beforeEach(() => {
      wrapper = mount(<Parent isReady={true}/>);
    });

it('Should render Child component', () => {
      expect(wrapper.prop('isReady')).to.equal(true); // Working !!
      expect(wrapper.find(Child).length).to.equal(1); // Not Working -> equal 0
    });
```

So far I double checked if the state is correctly changed, and it seems to be true when I check the wrapper's state of isReady. I'm pretty sure this part is working fine.

Also I tried wrapper.html() and even if isReady is true, I can see only the div part with my loader. The Child component which should be a `<form>..</form>` is never rendered. So If I try something like : `expect(wrapper.find('form').length).to.equal(1);` it's not working neither. I don't get why.

What should be the best practice here to test my parent behaviour and see if my child component inside is correctly rendered ?

**update:**

**1/** I've been through `console.log(wrapper)`, I can see the isReady is definitely true, but the only part rendered is the div with the loader. The nested component Child is never rendered. I have no idea why.. as I'm using mount and the prop/state is correctly set.

**2/** From what I can see it's the `{ isReady ? ... }` which is the problem because I'm doing a similar test in another component where I test if a parent component contains a nested component but this time there is no condition and it's working fine.

Comment: Have you tried to import `Child` in your test and check its length as: `wrapper.find(Child)` (removing the single quotes)?

Comment: @mersocarlin yes I've import my `Child` in my test but it's not working

Comment: but did you remove the single quotes as well?

Comment: Yes I tried without the quotes

Answer (score 5):

You should import the component in your test file and pass that instance to the find function rather than a string

```
import Child from 'path/to/child';
expect(wrapper.find(Child).length).to.equal(1);
```

Check **[this article on how to write the selectors](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/selector.html)**:

Also the result in this condition will still could be false since when you create a mounted instance of your parent you are not setting the `isReady` state if its already not initialised to true

In order to set the state of the test component use **[setState](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/setState.md)**

```
wrapper.setState({ isReady: true });
```

Comment: I've done that but not working. `expect(wrapper.find(Child).length).to.equal(1);`  return `AssertionError: expected 0 to equal 1`

Comment: Check the updated answer. You re not passing the isReady state will be false

Comment: What the problem now

Comment: Still same error : `AssertionError: expected 0 to equal 1
    at Assertion.assertEqual (packages/practicalmeteor_chai.js?hash=6d1fa4718a9857be0689dcd173706c8c205a341f:1425:12)
    at Assertion.ctx.(anonymous function) [as equal] (packages/practicalmeteor_chai.js?...` As I'm testing my react code in a meteorJS app it may be the problem.

Comment: Above example was not working for me because I was using React.memo and Enzyme doesn't support it yet. You can read about workarounds here: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1875