# Check if child component rendered - Jest, Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

In my unit test, I want to test whether the parent component is successfully rendering its child component. Here is the code:

```
describe('Parent Component', () => {
  it('renders Child component', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Parent store={store} />);
    expect(wrapper.find(Child).length).toEqual(1);
  });
});
```

Parent:

```
const Parent = observer(({ store }) => {
  const bookList = toJS(store.planets);
  return (
    <div>
      <div className={style.planet_container}>
        {bookList.map(book => {
          return <Child key={book.name} name={book.name} />;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
});
```

Above code is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47261674/enzyme-test-if-a-nested-component-is-correctly-rendered), but it's not working. I am getting the following error:

> Expected 1, Received 0'

Where am I going wrong? I am using Enzyme 3.3 with Jest 23.1.0.

Comment: You're trying to find a Child component inside a Child component. I think it should be something like this: `const wrapper = shallow(<Parent store={store} />);`

Comment: That was a typo while copying code here. Fixed above.

Comment: And are you importing that Child component in your test? if not, try this:
`expect(wrapper.find('Child').length).toEqual(1);`
or try to import the Child component.

Comment: Yes I am importing it, but still not working

Comment: Try to create your wrapper with `mount` bacause `shallow` doesn't render children. Check this out: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/465#issuecomment-227697726

Comment: I think I got the issue. `Child` only renders when `bookList` has some data. So how can I mock the `bookList` array in my test? (See code above, I made changes)

Comment: I created a gist to give you an idea, but im not sure if it works. https://gist.github.com/isafrus5/e648897868a608361410b1988388a0da

Answer (score 14):

You can check whether a parent component has rendered its child component using `containsMatchingElement()`.

Based on Enzyme [docs](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/containsMatchingElement.html):

> Returns whether or not a patternNode react element matches any element in the render tree.

Your test should look like this:

```
describe('Parent Component', () => {
  it('renders Child component', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Parent store={store} />);
    expect(wrapper.containsMatchingElement(<Child />)).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```

Comment: containsMatchingLement should be containsMatchingElement?

Comment: You did not define `Child` in your test file

Comment: @vsync make sure that you are including the Child component that you are testing in your test file hence the error

Answer (score 6):

[Enzyme](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/find.html) allows finding by a component's [displayName](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41581130/104380):

*From Enzyme API documentation:*

```js
const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
expect(wrapper.find('Foo')).to.have.lengthOf(1);
```

So, in order to test sure the Child component has been rendered you can simply reference it by its *[displayName](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41581130/104380)*.

You can [print the wrapper's HTML string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50050675/104380): `console.log( wrapper.debug() )`

---

In case your component is [dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29875869/104380) you can set its displayName to a fixed one, so the test would be more bulletproof:

```js
const MyComponent = props.dynamicChildComponent;
MyComponent.displayName = 'Foo';
```

Comment: I want to achieve the same ,but using react testing library.How can I do that??

Comment: @CodeOfLife - You aren't using *Enzyme*?

Comment: I am using react testing library

Comment: @CodeOfLife - this discussion here is only about `jest` + `enzyme`, for your question you need to either check if anyone else already asked this, and if not, open a new question. Asking new questions within comments of another is not good

Comment: For up-to-date expect library: expect(wrapper.find("Foo")).toHaveLength(1)

Answer (score 4):

Child is not rendering because you are not mocking the props (in this case the prop "store") correctly.

Try this:

```js
it('renders Child component', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow( < Parent / > );
  wrapper.setProps({
    store: {
      planets: [{
          name: "name 1"
        }
      ]
    }
  });
  expect(wrapper.find(Child)).toHaveLength(1);
});
```

Comment: You did not define `Child` in your test

Comment: I didn't define `Parent` either, they should be imported at the beginning of the file and the path depends on the specific project, so it's not relevant to the answer

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
describe('Parent Component', () => {
  it('renders Child component', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Parent />);
    expect(wrapper.find(Child)).toHaveLength(1);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check child component elements

```
 let wrapper1 = mount(<PersonalInfo {...personalInfodata} />);
    expect(wrapper1.find('ChildComponent').children(0).find('.description').text().length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
```

you can do something like this